# Blender 2.8 Troubles with PC

Tags: hardware

I bought a new laptop relatively recently, and I will list the specs below. Basically, I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem yet, searched for weeks, but when I use the Blender 2.8 Beta, after some amount of time (sometimes an hour, sometimes it will work longer) it will freeze. Then, I have to exit with task manage, but when I try to close Task Manager, it freezes too! (This behavior has only happened with blender 2.8 so far.) So I end up restarting my computer.

Any other version of Blender works just fine. All my games work fine, and nothing has been problematic except for blender, and I haven't seen this happen with anyone else.

My OpenGL version is 4.6. My Graphics Card is an NVidia, GeForce GTX 1050. My processor is an Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU, 2.8GHz.

Does anyone know why this could be happening? (And did I post the specs correctly? I am not a hardware person but I tried haha.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When does this freeze happens? Is it when you do something specific on blender like rendering or it happens randomly as you use blender?

Comment: Is Blender using excessive amounts of memory or CPU/GPU time? Have you upgraded your drivers to the latest versions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen at any particular action, I could be viewing in the viewport, I could be connecting nodes, or doing nothing. And yes I have updated to the latest drivers. It doesn't seem to be taking up much memory as well.